# How to programmatically save an object to SQL Server with .NET Core 2.0 and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I had to create some custom event logging in my .NET Core 2.0 MVC application. I also needed to be able to view the logs from the admin, but needed to save the events / objects programmatically. I am new to Core I struggled with it a little so I wanted to share what worked with me. I started a new project - ASP.NET Core Web Application (Model-View-Controller) with Individual User Accounts. I added a new Model (CustomErrorLogModel.cs) under Models.

```
    public class CustomErrorLogModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime ErrorDate { get; set; }
        public string ErrorType { get; set; }
        public string IPAddress { get; set; }
        public string URLAccessed { get; set; }
        public string UserAgent { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
    }
```

I added a new controller under Controllers and in the process I selected MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework - following the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model except I used my existing ApplicationDbContext - and performed the initial migration by opening the NuGet package manager console and running the following to generate the db table.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Add-Migration Initial
Update-Database
```

Then I created my CustomLogger.cs under Services

```
    public interface ICustomLogger
    {
        Task LogCustomErrorAsync(string message, string errorType, string IPAddress = null, string URLAccessed = null, string UserAgent = null);
    }

    public class CustomLogger:ICustomLogger
    {
        public AppSettingsModel AppSettings { get; }
        public CustomLogger(IOptions<AppSettingsModel> appsettingsAccessor)
        {
            AppSettings = appsettingsAccessor.Value;
        }

        public Task LogCustomErrorAsync(string message, string errorType, string IPAddress = null, string URLAccessed = null, string UserAgent = null)
        {
            LogCustomError(message, errorType, IPAddress, URLAccessed, UserAgent);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void LogCustomError(string message, string errorType, string IPAddress = null, string URLAccessed = null, string UserAgent = null)
        {
            DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext> optionsbuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            optionsbuilder.UseSqlServer(AppSettings.DefaultConnection);
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(optionsbuilder.Options))
            {
                CustomErrorLogModel customerror = new CustomErrorLogModel();
                customerror.Details = message;
                customerror.ErrorDate = DateTime.Now;
                customerror.ErrorType = "Information";
                customerror.IPAddress = IPAddress;
                customerror.URLAccessed = URLAccessed;
                customerror.UserAgent = UserAgent;
                context.CustomErrorLogModel.Add(customerror);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

In Startup.cs under ConfigureServices I added the service

```
services.AddTransient<ICustomLogger, CustomLogger>();
```

And I also added

```
services.Configure<AppSettingsModel>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
```

Now - as an example of calling the method. In EmailSender.cs my constructor looks like this:

```
public ICustomLogger _customLogger;   

public EmailSender(IOptions<MessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor, ICustomLogger customLogger)
{
    Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    _customLogger = customLogger;
}
```

and in the SendEmail method I log the events using the following:

```
_customLogger.LogCustomErrorAsync("SendEmail " + ex.Message, "Error");
```

I hope this will be helpful to others. Also, if you see anything wrong with the above that isn't necessarily best practice, please comment.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel! Other people have created logging frameworks. Your core job presumably isn't to create a logging framework. Take a look at [Serilog](https://serilog.net/), [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), log4net, Elmah etc.

Comment: I looked at them but  I wasn't sure if I needed an entire logging framework. Really the idea was to figure out how to save objects to the DB without using the views.

Comment: These logging frameworks are lightweight, more optimized and flexible than anything you can produce. Don't re-invent the wheel when it comes to logging! As for learning how to save arbitrary objects to database tables - you've got some code here. What about it doesn't work?

Comment: And when your business requirements change with more complex logging needs? If there is a slightest chance, then you should consider logging framework.

Comment: Can confirm setting up Serilog to write to SQL Server is extremely simple. Would definitely recommend.